# Microsoft Excel: How do I replace a cell's entered value with the formatted value, preferably with a text format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am cleaning an excel sheet for use in ArcGIS Pro. Many of the cells in this sheet are formatted as percentages with no decimal places, e.g. The entered value that appears in the formula bar might be 0.231456, while the value displayed in the cell is 23%. I want to replace all of these values as entered in the formula bar with their values as displayed in the cell, formatted as text, so that when I import the sheet to ArcGIS the values can be displayed in a table in a map layout. I do not need to retain the original 6-decimal-place values at all for calculation or analysis, just produce a sheet who's underlying cell values match the displayed values in the original sheet.

Comment: `=TEXT(A1,"#%")`

Answer (score 0):

You must select them somehow, so do so. If all the cells are in distinct columns, it will be super-easy. Or if all the cells in the workbook may have this change occur without causing you problems.

This method works in all circumstances when you select cells, but clearly, selecting one-by-one and using it would be work-intensive so... But I don't get the impression your skill set limits to you that method so you should be good.

Once selected (more than one cell selected, NOT just a single cell), you can go to `File|Options|Advanced|"When calculating this workbook"` and check `Set precision as displayed`. Keep a sharp eye on the status bar SUM at the bottom of the screen to ensure no surprises occur. Their recorded values ARE changing so it will too, but the scale of change should be from "0 to something fairly close, scaled, of course, due to data quantity." (100,000 cells with an average net change UP of 0.25 will be a larger change to the status bar SUM than 3,000 cells with the same average net change, and so on.) So consider the observed change for being in line with expectations. No cell can change by more than 0.5 so 100,000 of them should see no change greater than 50,000. That kind of thinking.

**This will only change the selected cells.** It will not change the rest. It only does a blanket change when a single cell is selected. I have not tested so what happens to those other cells if the workbook is saved, closed, and re-opened is something I do not know. So immediately after the change occurs (which is extremely fast), change the option back.

That handles their displayed value becoming their actual value.

For the Text formatting to be applied, before losing their selection status, bring up the formatting dialog and set their numeric format as Text.

All set.

If you selected a portion of them due to their circumstances, select another group and do them. "Rinse and repeat" so to speak (repeat the action on the new group that is).

There are a couple ways you could end up with something to concern you. One is that you might see something not change. In that case, it is already text, so "precision" doesn't apply to it. If you spot something like that, or wish to be proactive and be sure, then before making the `Options` change, format the selected cells as numbers in their desired two-digit percentage format. Watch the status bar SUM to ensure it does not become different. If it does, likely something whack occurred with a percentage becoming 2400% instead of its original appearance of 24% (someone had entered "24" not "0.24" in the original data somehow, et al.). So then, before doing the above, the data would need examined and cleansed.

The other would be entries not converting to the desired precision, yet really seeming not like text. That would be due to the whole slew of "usual suspects" commonly encountered with web data but certainly possible in "real" data sources as well. Once you figure out the difficulties and fix them, the above would work.

In any case, perhaps the data is reliable, only concern being the mechanics of the change. This will do it FAST and easy, depending on how hard it is to select the cells to start with. And you have to select them literally or virtually no matter the method you use. (By hand, by selecting cells next to them and using `TEXT()`, by using VBA to select them, however it might be, they have to be selected.) Super easy if you need not worry about other values present and can just operate on the whole workbook all at once.